# How to transform array column cells in items rows to count occurrences with pySpark?

Tags: arrays, pyspark, dataset, transformation

I have a dataset with multiple values in one column and I would like to count all occurrences of each values within all rows of the dataset.

```
initial dataset (example)
+----------------+
+ answers        +
+----------------+
+ val1#val2#val3 +
+ val2           +
+ val3#val5      +
+----------------+
Values are separated by #.

goal: 

+---------+-------+
+ values  + count +
+---------+-------+
+ val1    +  1    +
+ val2    +  2    +
+ val3    +  2    +
+ val5    +  1    +
+---------+-------+
```

The code is in pySpark

I used the split function to get an array of values.

```
df.withColumn("new_col", F.split("answers", "\#").
```

I have a dataset with an array column but I don't find how to use it properly.

I looked for many samples and functions which could help me but I didn't find and due to the fact that pySpark dataset are immutable, I didn't find a way to transform the array and compute occurrences.

Comment: Can you show about 5 rows of the array type column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `split` and `explode` to first get the values column.

Applying a `groupBy` on top of it would help achieve the desired counts.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, explode

df2 = df.withColumn("values", explode(split("answers", "\#")))

df2.groupBy("values").count().show()
```

Output:

```
+------+-----+
|values|count|
+------+-----+
|  val1|    1|
|  val3|    2|
|  val5|    1|
|  val2|    2|
+------+-----+
```